# How can I detect presence (and calculate extent) of overlapping speakers in audio file?

Tags: python, audio-processing

I have a collection of WAV audio files that contain broadcast recordings. Mostly audio parts of video recordings of news broadcasts etc. (I don't have the original videos). I need to estimate what %age of those files have overlapping speakers, i.e. when 2 or more people are talking more or less at the same time. And for those files where overlap does occur, what %age of those are overlapping speech. I don't care if it's 2, 3 or 23 people talking at the same time, as long as it's more than 1. Gender, age etc don't matter either. On the other hand, those recording are in many different languages, of varying quality, and may also contain background noise (street sounds, music etc). So this problem seems to be simpler than speaker diarization, but has complicating factors.

So is there a library (preferably Python) or a command line tool that can do this out of the box. One that does not require any supervised training (that is, I don't have any labeled data to train it with). Unsupervised training might be OK, but I prefer to avoid it too.

Thank you

UPDATE: Downstream processing of these files might define the task a bit better: Ultimately, we'll process them with ASR in order to index resulting transcripts for keyword search. When we search for a keyword "blah" in a multi-speaker recording, we won't care which speaker said it as long as any one of them did. Intuitively, getting "blah" correctly from a recording where there are multiple speakers but everyone carefully waits for their turn to speak would be easier than when everyone is speaking at the same time. I am trying to measure how much overlap is in those recordings. Among other things, this will allow me to quantitatively compare 2 sets of such recordings and conclude that one is harder than the other.

Comment: Can you define more precisely "more or less at the same time"? Are they speaking at the same time or not? First one makes things more complicated.

Comment: updated above -- does it clarify the task?

Comment: How about going with with existind end-to-end solutions like Google Speech to Text API https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/ ? I am not saying it's your solution, just trying to get to the bottom of what you guys need.

Comment: Won't work, unfortunately: need something that (i) is free and (ii) can be run locally

Comment: How about [CMU Sphinx](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/) then?

Comment: The problem of multiple-speaker detection is about as hard as your ASR problem. I don't think you will find out-of-the-box solutions. Instead I suggest that you build tools to isolate the sections where your ASR solutions does particularly badly, and then analyze those using unsupervised methods (clustering etc). This will help catch/understand any kind of situation that leads to underperformance, not just that which is caused by multiple simultanious speakers.

Comment: @IZ Did you find a solution?? It's been more than 1 year! Hope you did find something because I need the exact same thing i.e., Speech Overlap Detection

Comment: @JOSEPHBlessingh unfortunately, no